# I've been reviewing this code for hours but I'm not sure whats wrong with it

Tags: java

```
public class QuestionFive
{
// errors 




 public static void main (String [] args) 
   {

   double fallingDistance; // reutrn value of the method 
   final double g = 9.8;   // constant value of gravity 
   int s;                  // seconds  
   double value;           // stores our methods value 



   value = fallingDistance(); 

   system.out.println(value); 



         public static double fallingDistance(int s)
         {
            for (s = 1; s <= 10; s++)
                d = 0.5 * 9.8 * (s * s);
               return d;
         }
   }


}
```

QuestionFive.java:11: error: illegal start of expression
   public static double fallingDistance(int s)
   ^
QuestionFive.java:11: error: illegal start of expression
   public static double fallingDistance(int s)
          ^
QuestionFive.java:11: error: ';' expected
   public static double fallingDistance(int s)
                ^
QuestionFive.java:11: error: '.class' expected
   public static double fallingDistance(int s)
                                            ^

Comment: That's not a good title. A title should describe the problem specifically so people with relevant skill can help you easily

Answer (score 3):

You need to move your `fallingDistance` method out of the body of the `main` method. Java doesn't support definition of methods directly inside other methods.

```
public class QuestionFive {
  public static void main (String [] args) {
    // ...
  }  // Missing this brace.

  public static double fallingDistance(int s)
    // ...
  }

  // } // Remove this extraneous brace.
}
```

It is a lot easier to "debug" these issues yourself if you learn to correctly indent your code.

Answer (score 1):

you need to pass a value into your fallingDistance function call.

```
value = fallingDistance(7);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println("");
```

Should be with a capital s

Answer (score 0):

As stated above you can't create a method inside of the main method, so you have to move your method outside of the main method. This should clear up the illegal start to expression.

However, I don't think that you can have a method explicitly return multiple values as it seems you are trying to do in the above code. What you can do is make an array that will store each value that you that you can then call based by calling the array index in the main method.  Or as it stands now you can just call the method to print all of the values.  Hope this helps

```
public class Tester
{
    //these are the class variables so that you can call them
    //from any of the static methods in this class.
    public static final double gravity =  9.8; // meters/second
    public static int seconds = 0; //initial time
    public static double[] physics =  new double[10]; // declares and initializes the array to hold your values

    public static void main(String[]args)
    {
    doPhysics(); // the call for your method 

    //i represents the index value from 0-9 (based on it being a ten index array)
    for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
        System.out.println(Tester.physics[i]);
    }
    }

    public static void doPhysics()
    {

        for (int second = Tester.seconds; second < Tester.physics.length; second++){ // Tester. is needed because the variables are static and require the class reference
        Tester.physics[second] =  0.5 * Tester.gravity * (second * second); // second doubles as the array index and the current second 
        System.out.println("second: "+ second + "  "+ Tester.physics[second]);
        }
    }
}
```